# Twilio Client hold

Tags: twilio

I am working with node.js and the twilio client.

I am able to place a call on hold and retrieve it, however, only if I wait 6 seconds for the call to disconnect once I put it in the hold enqueue. If I try to disconnect the softphone once the caller is in the hold queue it disconnects the caller too.

```
function holdCall(){
    console.log(callStatus);
    //I am passing the agents name, and the current call status which is a boolean to the back end to modify the call so it is in a hold enqueue    
    socket.emit('holdCall', {agent: '{{client}}', status: callStatus});
    //If the call is currently on hold it returns true and I connect the agent to their custom queue
    if(callStatus){
        params = {"PhoneNumber": $("#number").val(), "State": "{{client}}"};
         call = Twilio.Device.connect(params);
    //if the call is not currently on hold then we want the twilio client to disconnect so the call can be taken off hold.
    }else{
      console.log(call);
      call.disconnect();
    }
    //switch the call status
    callStatus = !callStatus;


  }
```

If there is a better day to do this where I can just modify the live call to hook it back into the client who has not disconnected I would love to do it that way

Comment: Twilio evangelist here.  Have you looked at using TaskRouter (https://www.twilio.com/taskrouter) to manage the enqueuing and dequeueing of calls for you?  With TaskRouter you enqueue the call into a TaskQueue.  When an agent (or a worker in TaskRouter terms) becomes available the call gets assigned to them.  Twilio will proactively ask them to accept the Task (eg the call) and if they connect the two calls together.

Comment: @DevinRader how would that integrate with our current flow. Right now we have all of the routing built into our system. All we want to do is add in the ability to place calls on hold and retrieve them. Which we can do but there seems to be an issue with the Web RTC disconnecting the caller when they are already in hold. How would the call be offered to the agent? We don't want it to ring in we want the agent to press the hold button to take that call off hold. The way you describe it it would just be offered to the next available agent which is not really a hold feature

Comment: How are you putting the customer on "hold"?

Comment: I am moving them to an enqueue of hold. That works. Then to take them off queue I am moving them and the agent to another queue which works fine. The problem is that when you put them on hold it keeps the agents client open for 6 seconds. In that 6 seconds you can't take them off hold. If you let the system disconnect the client from the call it then allows you to take them off hold. However, if you try to disconnect the client after they are in the new hold queue it disconnects them too

Comment: Not sure I totally follow your workflow.  Mind taking this to email?  devin [at] twilio [dot] com.

Comment: Just to update anyone else having this issue I am still working with Twilio Support on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After speaking directly with Twilio Support I moved over to using conference rooms for everything and now it is working much more smoothly with no delays.